# Appium can't detect screen (visible: false) elements

Tags: cordova, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-ios

The project is a hybrid app using cordova to run both on android /ios platforms (focusing on ios right now). I've managed to setup Appium for automation testing  and it works just fine. Problem comes in the Appium inspector as it can see some elements but marks them as visible: false.

[screenshot of visible: false attribute in appium.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZRuU.png)

Test always fails every time it tried interacting (click, tap, sendKeys, etc) with these 'invisible' elements.
Sample:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")).click();

Logs in Appium when the error occurs:
[screenshot Appium logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KygMn.png)

Questions:

- How do I interact with these elements?
- What's the basis for marking them as visible: false?
- Is there anything I can change on my html markup to make the elements 'visible' true?

*I Noticed all of my vector icons are marked visible: false which is a huge problem as most of our navigation are icons.

*I already tried downgrading my Appium version to 2.1.0 (solution suggestion).

*Im using Java Client Appium 4.0.0, Selenium 2.53.1, Xcode 7.3.

Comment: have tried using driver.tap() method using location? and in ur code what is the error shown in appium log?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I updated the question with a screenshot of my logs. It keeps on returning me this error 'elementId 0 could not be tapped'.

Comment: how u use the tap method, using element or using locaiton?

Comment: I havent tried using .tap(), I though it was .click() cuz this is what Appium inspector generated when recording. What parameters are acceptable in driver.tap()? Can I just put in the xpath of my element?

Comment: tap(int fingers, int x, int y, int duration) and tap(int fingers, WebElement element, int duration)

use 1 as parameter in int fingers, x =3 and y = 662 for the first api and for second pass the element. use 700 as duration

api details http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/AppiumDriver.html

Comment: let me know what happens after using the tap api and also update ur tap api code how u use in ur question.

Comment: I used driver.tap(1, 311,  632, 700); and driver.tap(1, driver.findElement(By.xpath("/UIALink[1]/UIAStaticText[1]")), 700); I updated the x,y values based from my Appium inspector.

Comment: Test was successful but the button still wasn't clicked for some reason.

Comment: comment is not clear ....pls explain it more and give the error log

Comment: This icon button is the element I cant interact with. Using .click() returns the error with the screenshot in my question and fails the test. Using driver.tap() passes the test though the button still wasnt interacted (clicked).

Comment: Not sure on the error logs, it executed everything normally. Problem is the button still wasnt clicked -> it didnt respond to driver.tap()

Comment: the reason why it is not clicked is shown in log, please check it and provide it

Comment: this might help https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615141-isaccessibilityelement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try by using the below 2 api:

```
tap(int fingers, int x, int y, int duration)
```

and

```
tap(int fingers, WebElement element, int duration)
```

use 1 as parameter in int fingers, x =3 and y = 662 for the first api and for second pass the element. use 700 as duration

api details https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/…